Can't manage to use tmc2209 with rust and stm32g0xx-hal. How can I properly use the tmc2209 crate?
I'm trying to use the TMC2209 driver with stm32g071 via UART and there is the crate for this in Rust. I created a UART like this:
let mut dr_usart = dp
    .USART4
    .usart(
        (gpioa.pa0, gpioa.pa1),
        BasicConfig::default().baudrate(115_200.bps()),
        &mut rcc
    ) 
    .unwrap();

Similarly, I created an UART for communication with the computer, and it works perfectly when I use writeln!(). Did I understand correctly that I cannot read the entire incoming buffer with something like usart.read(&mut buf), and can only read byte by byte? Also I can't use usart.write_all(). Is this because I'm using an old version of HAL for stm32g0? As far as I know this related to my main problem:
So when I try to use the function tmc2209::send_write_request(0, gconf, &mut dr_usart); I get the error:
error[E0277]: the trait bound `Serial<USART4, BasicConfig>: hal::embedded_hal::blocking::serial::write::Default<u8>` is not satisfied
  --> src/main.rs:74:5
   |
74 |     tmc2209::send_write_request(0, gconf, &mut dr_usart);
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `hal::embedded_hal::blocking::serial::write::Default<u8>` is not implemented for `Serial<USART4, BasicConfig>`, which is required by `Serial<USART4, BasicConfig>: _embedded_hal_blocking_serial_Write<u8>`
   |
   = note: required for `Serial<USART4, BasicConfig>` to implement `_embedded_hal_blocking_serial_Write<u8>`

Is this because of the old stm32g0-hal? I tried various version of both crates but the problem is still the same.
And is there anything I can do other than manually implementing the functions I need?
Also, when I directly add the TMC2209 crate from git, the error changed, but I still don't understand how I can solve it:
error[E0277]: the trait bound `Serial<USART4, BasicConfig>: embedded_io::ErrorType` is not satisfied
  --> src/main.rs:74:5
   |
74 |     tmc2209::send_write_request(0, gconf, &mut dr_usart);
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `embedded_io::ErrorType` is not implemented for `Serial<USART4, BasicConfig>`
   |
   = help: the following other types implement trait `embedded_io::ErrorType`:
             &mut [u8]
             &[u8]
             &mut T


